# Blade component not showing using Alpinejs

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I tried to create a simple Laravel app with Alpinejs installed locally via Yarn. I followed a simple example from YT about creating Laravel blade components and it's working fine using the CDN version. But, not working on Alpinejs installed locally, and got the error below. [image]

*resources/views/components/input/group.blade.php*

```
@props(['label', 'error' => null])

<div x-data x-id="['input']" {{ $attributes }}>
    <label x-bind:for="$id('input')" {{ $attributes->class('block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900') }}>
        {{ $label }}
    </label>

    {{ $slot }}
</div>

@if ($error)
    <div class="text-sm text-red-600 !mt-1">{{ $error }}</div>
@endif
```

*resources/views/components/input/select.blade.php*

```
@aware(['error'])
@props(['error' => null])

<div>
    <select x-bind:id="$id('input')"
        {{ $attributes->class([
            'bg-gray-50 border text-gray-900 text-sm rounded focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5',
            'border-gray-300' => !$error,
            'border-red-500' => $error,
        ]) }}>
        {{ $slot }}
    </select>
</div>
```

*index.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="min-w-[300px]">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/alpine.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/tailwind.css') }}">
</head>

<body class="flex flex-col items-center">
    @verbatim
        <div class="max-w-[768px] min-h-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-black">
            <div class="p-8">
                <img src="test.jpg">

                <div x-data="alpineMixin" x-cloak class="space-y-3">
                    <x-input.group label="Your Age" class="text-white" :error="$errors->first('age')">
                        <x-input.select x-model="profile.age" name="age">
                            <template x-for="n in 53" :key="n">
                                <option :value="n + 17" x-text="n === 53 ? '70+' : n + 17"
                                    :selected="profile.age == n + 17"></option>
                            </template>
                        </x-input.select>
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endverbatim

    <script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Please note that I want to use alpinejs installed via yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, removing the @verbatim solves my issue. I think it's interfering with the rendering of Alpinejs components preventing the dynamic behavior from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine-ie11.min.js" integrity="sha512-Atu8sttM7mNNMon28+GHxLdz4Xo2APm1WVHwiLW9gW4bmHpHc/E2IbXrj98SmefTmbqbUTOztKl5PDPiu0LD/A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

you should try this above link CDN in your index blade